# Flutter for web did not resized by maximize chrome window

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-html

`Flutter (Channel master, v1.15.3-pre.37, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)`

When I maximize chrome window I get not right layout:

[image]

It's ok when window just resized.

I try `setState` with keys for widgets:

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", (e) {
      setState(() {});
    });
```

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      key: Key(Uuid().v4()),
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
```

Or with `WidgetsBindingObserver`:

```dart
print(WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize);
```

It's every time get previous value of screen size in `didChangeMetrics`.

Maximize window event should work like resize.
How can I fix that?

Comment: All resized right if remove `FloatingActionButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Issues with Flutter web rendering are caused by CanvasKit. Try switching to html renderer and see if similar issues persists. You can run the web app with `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html`

If the web app has issues with the CanvasKit renderer, it's best to report this to Flutter's GitHub [issue tracker](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/).